# Internal Link Resolution Issue

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am getting a freak behavior as stated below (The environment is SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 with HotFix Rollup applied):

I have a page - Page 1 - with say following components on it associated thru' different static Templates:
1) Component 1

2) Component 2

3) Component 3

I have another page - Page 2 -  with Component 4 on it. Component 4 is having an internal link to Component 1.

Both the pages are published multiple times.

Now my expectation is that the internal link on Page 2 should get resolved at run time to link to Page 1. but this is not happening - This might be simple to crack if this is the only issue - but now the real trouble - If Component 4 on Page 2 is edited to have internal link to Component 2 then everything works fine and internal link on Page 2 correctly points to the Page 1.

Any suggestion or data point that could check?

One thing that I have done is that I have re-positioned the Page from one structure group to another structure group after un-publishing it followed by the publishing of it.

Please note:
1) All the pages and structure group hierarchy is published multiple times

2) All other internal links are working fine

3) If I see the preview mode of these pages, they generate the expected code including the one for internal linking

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "this is not happening" - is no link resolved *at all* or just the wrong link?

Comment: There's always a valid reason underneath it... all I can say is check your cd_core log (set it in debug) for linking information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nuno, unfortunately I do not have privileges to edit logging configuration :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phew...Finally I was able to resolve the issue after checking that everything was correct.

Logically everything seems correct...so I went the illogical way....removed all the reference from pages, re-create the specific component and re-link them in the pages...publish them...and woo hoo...it starts working....remembered the Microsoft way..If your Windows is giving problem...just re-start it :( ... I would love to explore the reason though :(

Answer (score 2):

You might need to check your Compoennt Template priorities. Are Components 1 & 2 using the same Component Template on Page 1. Make sure they are not set to "Never Link"

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply.
Unfortunately, I have already checked and the Priority of Component Template is set to "Medium".